# RegExp restrict all symbols except numbers and several letters after them if they persist

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I try to build a custom `RegExp` pattern for allowing only numbers on input, besides if some letters were inputted after these numbers it should allow them. **BUT** not only in case if no numbers were inputted before letters.

So I make a tiny regexp, but it even allows `k` and `m` letters on input without any numbers on the beginning. That's bad...

Can someone tell me where am I wrong?

Example:

```
const matchPattern = new RegExp(/[^0-9(k|m)?]$/, 'gi')

'2323'.match(matchPattern) - // true
'23234k'.match(matchPattern) - // true
'23234m'.match(matchPattern) - // true
'k'.match(matchPattern) - // true, BUT should be false
'm'.match(matchPattern) - // true, BUT should be false
```

Comment: This `[^` means a negated character class. Your pattern matches any single char except `0-9`, `(`, `k`, `|`, `m`, `)`, or `?` at the end of the string `$` You could try `^\d+[km]?$` https://regex101.com/r/LJ9KsZ/1/

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird . unfortunately it not working as expected ( ... The same thing the leading k|m is allowed here.

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using to the question? The pattern does not allow a leading `k`. Did you check the regex link?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I've updated my question. So yeah, thanks your pattern is right, besides I'm looking only for negated one :( ....

Comment: I am curious, why do you want to use a negated pattern?

Comment: @Thefourthbird "I think you don't mean like this" - I really need it as negated! Well, the current system where I need a regexp pattern can process only with negated one... That's a pity, yeah.

Comment: If you want only numbers first and then optionally a letter, you could try 2 negated character classes `^[^\D]+[^\W\d_a-jln-z]?$` https://regex101.com/r/10Gd4f/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks a lot for your advice! Nevertheless, any symbol classes won't let you work within `new RegExp` negated literal, i.e. `var a = '\d'; // new RegExp(a); === new RegExp('d');`, not as `\d`.

Comment: You have to double escape the backslash.

Comment: @Thefourthbird wow! Thanks a lot! Make your question as an answer and I'll voute it up!

Comment: I have added it as an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) only, you might use:

```
^[^\D]+[^\W\d_a-jln-z]?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/10Gd4f/1)

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\D]+` Match 1+ times any char except not a digit (match a digit)
- `[^\W\d_a-jln-z]?` Optionally match any char except not a word char, digit, _ or a-z range except `k` and `m`
- `$` End of string

```js
const matchPattern = new RegExp("^[^\\D]+[^\\W\\d_a-jln-z]?$", "i");
console.log('2323'.match(matchPattern));
console.log('23234k'.match(matchPattern));
console.log('23234m'.match(matchPattern));
console.log('k'.match(matchPattern));
console.log('m'.match(matchPattern));
```